# chmod will not work on entries of a directory

Tags: bash, sudo, glob

How come on this folder

```
sudo ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/archive/jenkinsv2.sfucsss.org/
total 20
-rw-r--rwx 1 root root 1927 Oct 17 22:58 cert1.pem
-rw-r--rwx 1 root root 1647 Oct 17 22:58 chain1.pem
-rw-r--rwx 1 root root 3574 Oct 17 22:58 fullchain1.pem
-rw----rwx 1 root root 1675 Oct 19 21:15 privkey-rsa.pem
-rw----rwx 1 root root 1704 Oct 17 22:58 privkey1.pem
```

Doing `sudo chmod -R o-rwx /etc/letsencrypt/archive/jenkinsv2.sfucsss.org/` work but doing

```
sudo chmod -R o-rwx /etc/letsencrypt/archive/jenkinsv2.sfucsss.org/*
chmod: cannot access '/etc/letsencrypt/archive/jenkinsv2.sfucsss.org/*': No such file or directory
```

Does not?

Comment: Maybe because you don't have permissions to write on the folder. Check `ls -ld /etc/letsencrypt/archive/jenkinsv2.sfucsss.org`

Comment: BTW, are you sure you tried `sudo chmod -R o-rwx /etc/letsencrypt/archive/jenkinsv2.sfucsss.org/*` and not `sudo chmod -R o-rwx "/etc/letsencrypt/archive/jenkinsv2.sfucsss.org/*"`?

Comment: `*` is expanded as your normal user *before* `sudo` runs - presumably your normal user cannot read the folder